# Cluster groups having the same label and are next to each other

Tags: r

I’m unable to find a good solution, but I think there might be even a base or tidyverse R function that could do that:

My Data:

| Row | Label |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | NA |
| 2 | Foo |
| 3 | Foo |
| 4 | Foo |
| 5 | NA |
| 6 | NA |
| 7 | Foo |
| 8 | Foo |
| 9 | NA |
| 10 | Foo |
| 11 | NA |
| ... | ... |

What I want:

| Row | Label | FooCluster |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NA | NA |
| 2 | Foo | 1 |
| 3 | Foo | 1 |
| 4 | Foo | 1 |
| 5 | NA | NA |
| 6 | NA | NA |
| 7 | Foo | 2 |
| 8 | Foo | 2 |
| 9 | NA | NA |
| 10 | Foo | 3 |
| 11 | NA | NA |
| ... | ... | ... |

Is there something elegant out there?
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `base R`, this can be done with `rle`

```
df1$FooCluster <- inverse.rle(within.list(rle(is.na(df1$Label)), {
         values[values] <- NA
         values[!is.na(values)] <- seq_along(values[!is.na(values)])}))
```

-output

```
df1
#   Row Label FooCluster
#1    1  <NA>         NA
#2    2   Foo          1
#3    3   Foo          1
#4    4   Foo          1
#5    5  <NA>         NA
#6    6  <NA>         NA
#7    7   Foo          2
#8    8   Foo          2
#9    9  <NA>         NA
#10  10   Foo          3
#11  11  <NA>         NA
```

---

Or with `rleid` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, grp := rleid(!is.na(Label))][!is.na(Label), 
      FooCluster := .GRP , grp][, grp := NULL][]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Row = 1:11, Label = c(NA, "Foo", "Foo", "Foo", 
NA, NA, "Foo", "Foo", NA, "Foo", NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

Comment: Thank you so much @akrun. It is always mind-blowing, how people on SO come up with such magic lines <3

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option using nested `cumsum` (however, the logic behind is not as simple as the [answer by @akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66694342/12158757))

```
transform(
  df,
  FooCluster = replace(
    rep(NA, length(Label)),
    !is.na(Label),
    cumsum(diff(c(0, cumsum(is.na(Label))[!is.na(Label)])) > 0)
  )
)
```

which gives

```
   Row Label FooCluster
1    1  <NA>         NA
2    2   Foo          1
3    3   Foo          1
4    4   Foo          1
5    5  <NA>         NA
6    6  <NA>         NA
7    7   Foo          2
8    8   Foo          2
9    9  <NA>         NA
10  10   Foo          3
11  11  <NA>         NA
```